# Problem when compiling linux using sudo make

Tags: kernel, compiling, gcc, make

I have a serious problem when compiling linux when putting `sudo make`, I get this quite unknown error that I could not find in Google

```
pikachuandeevee2000@Ubuntu-PC:/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-17# sudo make
  SYNC    include/config/auto.conf.cmd
  HOSTCC  arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o
In file included from arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.c:2:
arch/x86/tools/relocs.h:18:10: fatal error: tools/le_byteshift.h: No such file or directory
   18 | #include <tools/le_byteshift.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:112: arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o] Error 1
make: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:210: archscripts] Error 2
```

How do I fix this?, I have been adding a custom image to the text based boot using make menuconfig.

Answer (score 1):

Install the matching `linux-headers` package for that kernel.

And you need `sudo` only for `sudo make install`, **not** for plain `make`. Don't use `sudo` if you don't really need root privileges.

Comment: Thanks  had already solved it but now I get this error more serious than the previous one  scripts/selinux/genheaders/genheaders.c:18:10: fatal error: classmap.h: No such file or directory

Comment: With that level of Google skills, you are in for a rough ride.